# cell operations - add operation every cell

Tags: matlab

I have a `mat2cell A` 12*12 blocks cell, each cell 8*8 pixels. Then I have `mat2cell B`, 8*8 blocks cell, with each cell 8*8 pixels.

I want to make operation that every cell in `mat2cell` `B` add with whole cell in `mat2cell A`.

```
A = mat2cell(x, [8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8] , [8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8]);
B = mat2cell(y, [8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8] , [8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8]);
```

I want `A{1,1}` to be added to each cell `B{1,1}`, `B{1,2}`, `B{3,5}`, same for A{1,2}, and so on.

Comment: I must misread this question as it appears that you are trying to add vectors of different length. Could you include an example of desired output?

Comment: but the size of every cell is same. i think it can be added between cell in A and B. i dont know the looping process for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear what you mean by `"whole cell in mat2cell A"`. In A you have 144 (12*12) cells and you want to add every one of those cells to each cell in B?

If this is the case then I would start by condensing all of the 144 cells in A into one cell of 8*8 pixels. If you are adding every element of A to B then first add all the elements of A together before adding to B in one go.

So to start with A, this will give you a 3 dimensional numerical array - the 3rd dimension being your 144 cells

```
Amat=cell2mat(A(:)');
A3D = reshape(b,8,8,144);
```

You can then sum all of the pixels along the 3 dimension, putting the result back in a cell array

```
Asum = {sum(A3D,3)};
```

Now you have the summed values of A in a single cell of 8*8 pixels which you can then duplicate to match the size of your array B.

```
AA = repmat(Asum,8,8);
```

Finally to add the two cell arrays use cellfun

```
C = cellfun(@plus,AA,B,'UniformOutput',false);
```

This will add every element of A, from A{1,1} through to A{12,12} on to B{1,1} and then B{1,2} etc. upto B{8,8}